# How do you grep/ag in specific subdirectory of a project?

Tags: helm, projectile

`projectile-grep`s are probably the commands that I use the most. However, with some very large projects I am frequently interested in grepping only one subdirectory of the project. For my greps I usually use `helm-projectile-ag`but it recursively greps in project's root.

The closest think that I have found is `helm-do-grep-ag` but it works on `default-directory`. To achieve the effect on grepping specific directory I first have to set that directory as `default-directory`.

How do you achieve grepping in project's subdirectory?
Is there some parameter that I am terribly missing somewhere?

Comment: At minimum, `M-x rgrep` will let you do this.  (or `M-x lgrep` if you don't want recursive searching).  I'd be surprised if other facilities don't have that as an option, though.  Have you tried using a prefix argument?

Answer (score 3):

For `grep` itself, <kbd>M-x</kbd> `rgrep` (recursive from specified directory), and <kbd>M-x</kbd> `lgrep` (specified directory only) let you do this.

Answer (score 2):

To achieve what you described I use: [helm-ag](https://github.com/syohex/emacs-helm-ag) package. `helm-do-ag` interactive function will prompt you for the directory where to search. Just bind it to your preferred key shortcut.

Comment: How to setq the directory or directories where to search? I would like to use helm-do-grep-ag so it always searches within specific folders. Is this possible? Thanks!

Comment: I have a small function to do this: https://github.com/daviderestivo/galactic-emacs/blob/420da433c07e6fa1b54daf5fce3730b627b47f10/conf/helper-functions.el#L142

Comment: Thanks, @Davide Restivo. I'm a newbie in elisp. If I wanted to change org directory for.a specific path, how would I replace that in your function? I really don't understand it :/ Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @EmmanuelGoldstein: [here](https://gist.github.com/daviderestivo/48fb7434c08c45caa191b8b160c61b48) a simplified version that searches in your Document folder and add a keybinding to <f5>. I hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. I replaced helm-do-ag with helm-ag, and it's very useful as it works the same as helm-do-ag, but it prompts for a second search within those found items.